# how do I split this php file into MVC format?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

i'm learning to program in OOP MVC,

I have this code for a simple nav menu:

```
<?php  
$directory = "views";
$scannedDirectory = glob("$directory/*.php");

function uppercaseSpace($str) {
    $re = '/(?=[A-Z][a-z])(?<!^)|(?=[A-Z])(?<=[a-z])/m';
    $subst = ' ';
    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

    return $result;
}
?>
<div id="header2">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" href="http://<?php echo $HOST ?>">Home</a>
            </li>
            <?php foreach ($scannedDirectory as $key => $value) {
                $articleName = substr($value,6,-4);
                printf(' 
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="?page=%s">%s</a>
                    </li>
                    ',$articleName, ucfirst(uppercaseSpace($articleName)));
                } ?>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div> <!-- /header -->
```

I have a function in the php file so I could make a class navmenu.class and make a method of this function and put the frist 2 lines in the class as a property and the last html part becomes a view right?

but is this class a model or is it a controler?

here is a screenshot of my current file structure:

[image]

Is it worth to split this small code into MVC?

This file is now put in the subfolder **includes** because I am *including* the nav menu in my script.

Comment: You should start with just learning basics of OOP. Look at what "SOLID principles" are and try to apply them in your project. And be careful of various "mvc tutorials" - they usually are completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models are for database, View to render html, Controllers to handle a request 
Beside that you can have helper classes and core classes

Follow some tutorials on how to create a mvc.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OsCTzGASImQ&list=PLfdtiltiRHWGXVHXX09fxXDi-DqInchFD

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkaLJrYnpOM&list=PLFPkAJFH7I0keB1qpWk5qVVUYdNLTEUs3

I followed the one of Curtis Parham he explained everything very well. After completing his tutorial I modified his framework alot by including composer, twig and changed the routing on how to handle variables and multiple languageses.

Comment: ahh that makes perfect sense, if it's not database related then I don't make it a MVC.
Thanks, I'm watching the MVC course right now, great tip

Comment: Wow, those videos were even more terrible than I suspected. That BS has nothing to do with MVC.